# passing object to component using v-for

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for, vue-props

I am trying to send a series of objects that are in an array to a child component using `v-for`, but when I try to access them from the child component, it tells me that the props are not defined.
Im using `Quasar Framework` actually

This is how I pass the data:

```html
<div class="row justify-center">
   <foo
      v-for="brand in brands"
      :key="brand.id"
      :brand="brand"
      ></foo>
</div>
<script>
import foo from "src/components/foo.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    foo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      brands: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getData() {
      let x = await get.getData();
      this.brands = x.data;
      console.log(this.brands);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData();
  }
};
</script>
```

`brands` is an array that obtains two objects from a request made to a local database, which I have already verified that it receives the data correctly

And this is the component file and how I try to get the properties:

```html
<q-card class="my-card" flat bordered>
   <q-img
      :src="require(`../assets/${brand.img}`)"
      :alt="brand.img + ' Logo'"
   />

   <div class="text-h5 q-mt-sm q-mb-xs">{{ brand.name }}</div>
      <div class="text-caption text-grey">
         <p>
            {{ brand.price }}
         </p>
      </div>
<script>
export default {
  name: "foo",
  props: ["brand"],
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: false
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

but when I try to execute the code it gives me the following error:

`Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './undefined'`

I know one way to make it work, and it is by creating a property for each of the object's values, for example:

```html
<component
   v-for="brand in brands"
   :key="brand.id"
   :name="brand.name"
   :price="brand.price"
   ></component>
```

But I dont think thats the correct way to do this....

Comment: I wouldn't call your component `component` as surely that will conflict with Vue's built-in [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Comment: @Phil I dont call component ```component``` on the original code...I changed the name here for be more easiest to read

Comment: I suggest you fix up your question to better match reality. As can be seen by the answer below, this is currently quite confusing

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the error message. _"Error: Cannot find module './undefined'"_ is not saying anything about props not being defined. You would only get that error from a dynamic `import` or `require` or possible an `<img>` tag but none of those appear in your question at all. This needs a lot more detail and debugging steps before it can be answered

Comment: yes you are right, i have an image and its where i get the error. I can have acces to other properties. But what it means that error when comes from an image?? I am going to modify the question so that the image tag is visible

Comment: If this were my code, I'd start without the component. Create a div with a v-for, and paste the markup from the component into the parent.  I'd start without the image.  Then I'd add the image.  Only then, I'd try move the running code into the component.

Comment: Either the error message reported in your question does not match the one you are actually receiving or the code in your question does not match. I cannot see anything in the current code that would cause _"Cannot find module './undefined'"_

Comment: the error comes from ```:src="require(`../assets/${brand.img}`)"``` it seems as if the string is not constructed well

Comment: Do some debugging. What type of values are in `brand.img`? Do they align with image files in the `src/assets` directory?

Comment: Yes i found the error...im using orm sequelize, but i dont know whe the field img its not in response...i have to check that but thx to you I found the error. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
import component from "src/components/component.vue";
```

to

```
import foo from "src/components/component.vue";
```

on your components section you just call `foo` instead of `foo:component`

Comment: OP's question is quite confusing as they started with `component` and then half-changed to `foo` but I don't think this is the problem

Comment: @Phil didn't saw the previous edit version, might not be the problem.
but undefined as error message might point to import problem

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but:

Looks like ${brand} is empty. Your function GetData() is async, so the `<foo>` is created before the GetData() has its data set/returned.

You can change
`<foo v-for="brand in brands" :key="brand.id" :brand="brand"></foo>`
To
`<foo v-if="brands.length> 0" v-for="brand in brands" :key="brand.id" :brand="brand"></foo>`
To make sure that the element is renderd after the data if set.

Note: v-if is when the html is rendered, v-show is just a css display hide, but the html is always renderd